# unblur image while scrolling using Angular JS 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create this effect using Angular JS 1 where as you scroll the background image of a div changes from a blurred one to a clearer one. I have done this using basic HTML, CSS, and JS and I have read that you can use simple JS functions in an angular app. My previous code is something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="intro">
   <div class="img-src"></div>
   <div class="img-src scroll-img"></div>
   Hello
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
.intro{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.img-src{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url('../assets/cover-image-blur.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -10;
    background-color: #222;
}
.scroll-img{
    background-image: url('../assets/cover-image.png');
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: -0.006677;
}
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var oVal;
        oVal = $(window).scrollTop() / 240;
        return $('.scroll-img').css('opacity', oVal);
    });
}.call(this));
```

I tested it on WAMP server and the image didn't even show. Then I tried putting it on Github pages. The image did show but the height was only till the text "Hello". I want it to be full 100% of the browser window so I used height 100% in the CSS. Please help! Thanks!